# Plot with Min/Max bar and two average points

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, errors, charts

I am trying to stop using Excel charts in my academic papers and rather use something more LaTeX integrated such as Tikz.

My current Excel chart looks like that:
[image: I have]
As can be seen, any combination from the two sets {CR, ER, CRER} and {10, 50, 100} contains four information: Avg, AvgOpen, Min and Max.

I would like to draw, for each combination, one single bar: One bar that spans from Min to Max and two different points that indicate Avg and AvgOpen.

Searching on the web, the closest to what I want looks like that:

[image: I would like to have]

However, I could only find solutions like the one discussed here:
[Link to other discussion thread:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81693/pgfplots-with-symbolic-x-coords-and-error-bars)
[pgfplots with symbolic x coords and error bars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81693/pgfplots-with-symbolic-x-coords-and-error-bars)
In this example, the min and max values can be well identified, but there is only one single point to indicate the avg. How could I add another point to such an example?

Also, in the Excel chart you can see that I have two lines of labels on the x-axis. For example a "CR" which is then sub-divided into 10, 50 and 100. Does anybody have an indication how I could create such a chart?

Many thanks in advance. Any kind of help is appreciated.

San

==========================================

I managed to build a chart according to what I would like to have. Now I just have to add a legend, which does not quite work out. Using normal bars, I can add a legend. However, using error bars I didn't yet figure out how. Please consider my current code:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\pgfplotsset{
    min max/.style={
        mark=-,
        error bars/.cd,
            y dir=plus,
            y explicit,
            error mark=-,
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
            x=Time,
            y=Min,
            y error expr=\thisrow{Max}-\thisrow{Min}
    },
    avg avgopen/.style={
        mark=*, mark size=2pt, %mark options={xshift=-2pt},
        error bars/.cd,
            y dir=plus,
            y explicit,
            error mark=square,
%            error mark=|,
%            error bar style={draw opacity=0,xshift=3pt},
%            error mark options={draw opacity=1, mark size=3pt},
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
            x=Time,
            y=AvgOpen,
            y error expr=\thisrow{Avg}-\thisrow{AvgOpen}
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
Time    Avg AvgOpen Min Max
CR  8.63    5.81    4   10
ER  8.17    6.31    3   10
CRER    8.42    5.84    4   10
}\datatableA

\pgfplotstableread{
Time    Avg AvgOpen Min Max
CR  25.02   15.84   6   44
ER  23.17   16.97   6   43
CRER    24.15   15.73   6   45
}\datatableB

\pgfplotstableread{
Time    Avg AvgOpen Min Max
CR  48.24   38.18   13  86
ER  45.47   39.41   12  82
CRER    47.19   38.29   12  85
}\datatableC



\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{C{.26\textwidth}C{.26\textwidth}C{.26\textwidth}C{.20\textwidth}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [10 loc] {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [symbolic x coords={CR,ER,CRER},xtick=data,width=0.30\textwidth,height=0.4\textwidth,
                %legend entries={Min, Max, Avg, AvgOpen},
                %legend to name=legend:legend-stats1   
                legend pos=north west,
]
\addplot [min max][forget plot,only marks]  table {\datatableA};
\addplot [avg avgopen][forget plot,only marks] table {\datatableA};
%\legend{$S$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [50 loc] {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [symbolic x coords={CR,ER,CRER},xtick=data,width=0.30\textwidth,height=0.4\textwidth]
\addplot [min max][forget plot,only marks]  table {\datatableB};
\addplot [avg avgopen][forget plot,only marks] table {\datatableB};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [100 loc] {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [symbolic x coords={CR,ER,CRER},xtick=data,width=0.30\textwidth,height=0.4\textwidth]
\addplot [min max][forget plot,only marks]  table {\datatableC};
\addplot [avg avgopen][forget plot,only marks] table {\datatableC};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} &
%\ref{legend:legend-stats1}
\end{tabular}
\caption{My chart.}
\end{figure}
```

This gives me a chart such as the following one:

[image: My chart]

Now, I would like to add a legend to the right of the 3 subfigures, vertically aligned in the center or at the top, with the following four entries (showing the corresponding symbol):
- Min
- Max
- Avg
- AvgOpen

Furthermore, I would like to have a little less (horizontal) space between each of the bars.

As mentioned, I was trying to manage this since some time now and I just don't find the right commands.

Any help is appreciated! Many thanks in advance.

San

Comment: This should be possible to implement in PGFPlots. Is this trading data? From a quick web search, it seems like it's more common to plot min, max, open and close instead of min, max, average, average open, though?

Comment: Hello, it is not trading data. That may work, however. Do you have a link for the case where open and close is plotted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `error bar` functionality and combine two `\addplot` commands to achieve this.

Here are two styles, `min max` and `avg avgopen` that you can apply to two `\addplot` commands to generate the plots like so:

```
\pgfplotstableread{
Time AvgOpen Avg Min Max
0 7 8 5 10
1 8 7 6 11
2 6 10 5 15
3 8 9 4 10
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[only marks]
\addplot [min max] table {\datatable};
\addplot [avg avgopen] table {\datatable};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    min max/.style={
        mark=empty,
        error bars/.cd,
            y dir=plus,
            y explicit,
            error mark=empty,
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
            x=Time,
            y=Min,
            y error expr=\thisrow{Max}-\thisrow{Min}
    },
    avg avgopen/.style={
        mark=-, mark size=4pt, mark options={xshift=-4pt},
        error bars/.cd,
            y dir=plus,
            y explicit,
            error mark=|,
            error bar style={draw opacity=0,xshift=4pt},
            error mark options={draw opacity=1, mark size=4pt},
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
            x=Time,
            y=AvgOpen,
            y error expr=\thisrow{Avg}-\thisrow{AvgOpen}
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
Time AvgOpen Avg Min Max
0 7 8 5 10
1 8 7 6 11
2 6 10 5 15
3 8 9 4 10
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[only marks]
\addplot [min max] table {\datatable};
\addplot [avg avgopen] table {\datatable};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Many Thanks! Please see below a follow-up question.

Comment: I just added my follow-up as an 'edit' to my previous question. If you find some time, I would be very thankful if you could have a look. In any case you have already been very helpful, thanks!