# Overlay bar plots to do asymmetric errorbars?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

[To illustrate the problem, I use the code from the answer of this link for asymmetric errorbars in pgfplots.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81693/pgfplots-with-symbolic-x-coords-and-error-bars)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
x         y    y-max  y-min
Lighting  0.12 0.31   0.03
Computers 0.06 0.12   0.01 
Total     0.07 0.14   0.02
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3] 
\begin{axis} [symbolic x coords={Lighting,Computers,Total},xtick=data]
\addplot+[forget plot,only marks] 
  plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
  table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-max}] {\mytable};
\addplot+[only marks,xticklabels=\empty] 
  plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=minus, y explicit]
  table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-min}] {\mytable};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I need for my presentation a barplot with asymmetric errorbars. Is it possible to overlay two errorbarplots to draw the error bars? How can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with PGFPlots 1.9, asymmetric error bars are directly supported, so you can simply use a single `\addplot [ybar]` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
x         y    y-max  y-min
Lighting  0.12 0.31   0.03
Computers 0.06 0.12   0.01 
Total     0.07 0.14   0.02
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    ymin=0,
    symbolic x coords={Lighting,Computers,Total},
    xtick=data
]
\addplot [ybar, fill=gray!50] 
  plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
  table [y error plus=y-max, y error minus=y-min] {\mytable};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```