# pgfplots - with errorrange doesn't match its definition

Tags: pgfplots, errors, bar-chart

I'd like to add error bars to a bar plot, making the situation very similar to [pgfplots - plusminus doesn't match its definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195018/pgfplots-plusminus-doesnt-match-its-definition).

But I get a different error. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xticklabels = {xlabel},
    ybar = 0.2pt,
]

\addplot[error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
    coordinates {
(1, 0.9798043478262296) += (0, 0.012972979771813395) -= (0, 0.012972979771813395)

};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is the error:

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': you might benefit from \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} (current compat level: 1.6).

! Use of \pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@NEXT@WITH@ERRORRANGE doesn't match its definition.
<argument>  (1, 0.9798043478262296) +=
                                       (0, 0.012972979771813395) -= (0, 0.01...
l.41 };

? X
No pages of output.
```

When I comment out the `+= ...` part, the code compiles. What should I do?

Comment: For me your example works as it is. I am using PGFPlots v1.14. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow Package: pgfplots 2012/10/26 v1.7 Data Visualization (1.7-2-ge24fff4). I'll consider using a newer version.

Comment: Sounds good. Please let us know if updating PGFPlots fixed the issue.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Updating PGFPlots did fix the issue. Although I found the hardest part to be figuring out that I (also) needed to copy the contents of the generic folder to my local installation directory tree in order to update the package. Thank you.

Comment: There should be no need for that. But this is a completely new question which we shouldn't discuss here in the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved by updating PGFPlots.